# How do I set up socket.io 1.0 (unstable)?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I have spent several hours playing around on ununtu trying to upgrade my socket.io 0.8 to socket.io 1.0

I have tried testing my applicaiton and have found many people cannot connect. Using 1.0 I have heard it is likely to solve this issue as it handles transport upgrades better. Socket.io 1.0 is likely to come out anytime soon, but has been in the 'nearly ready' state for many months and I am looking for some detailed instructions on how to download, build and use in ubuntu.

I have looked at the forums over on github + google groups, including these threads:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/JrL6cN6gTig
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/DC07mM2WpNk

However I am still having no luck. The closest I have got, is having my server not complain, however my socket.io/socket.io.js file served to the client, is just an (almost) empty js file with one line which is just a relative directory in node_modules to a js file.

I am really just asking if there is any detailed instructions around for this? Any help would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Hi im using express web application framework with node.js.My below code is working fine with socket.io Also i'm getting socket.io.js in client without any problem.

Server.js

```
           var express = require('express')
                           , http = require('http');

           var app = express();
           app.configure(function(){
           app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
           });
           var server = http.createServer(app);
           var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
           server.listen(8000);
```

In index.html file i have added below code so it gets the socket.io in client without any problem.

```
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, are you using socket.io 0.9 (stable) or the 1.0 release (unstable which uses engine.io)? As setting up standard socket.io/express/nodejs I have already running it is more the unstable socket.io I am looking to setup.

Comment: @jezternz my socket.io version is "~0.9.6"